# Perl script returning value in makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

I have a perl script which returns value "return 1;" or "return 0;".I tried also "exit 1;" and "exit 0;"

In my makefile I have the following code:

```
ifneq ($(TRG_TYPE),node)
    VAR := $(shell perl $(ROOT)/Make/chipdep.pl $(ROOT) $(CHIP) $(NAME) ) 
ifeq ($(VAR),1)
    $(error just a test error. Aborting)
endif
endif
```

I know that perl script works - I tested it separately, but I never see this error and abort, even when it should be seen!

Answer (score 0):

The value of a `shell` invocation is the output of the shell command, not its exit code. Make your script `print 0` or `print 1`, or in the general case, do `$(shell yourcmd >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)` to obtain just the exit code from a `shell` command.

This seems slightly backwards, though. If your script returns 0 for success and 1 for failure, maybe you should simply run it as the first command of your target; the target will abort if any of its commands fail.

Comment: I do not need to distinguish between success and failure, just two different case that must be treated differently

Comment: Now this $(shell yourcmd >/dev/null 2>&1; exit $$?)  is working , but $$? is always holding 0

Comment: Maria: triplee meant to write `echo`, not `exit`: `$(shell yourcmd >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)`

Comment: I wrote:VAR := $(shell perl $(ROOT)/Make/chipdep.pl $(ROOT) $(CHIP) $(NAME) >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
 @echo $$?    And i get: "bin/dash:VAR: not found"

Comment: Sounds like you are writing it in a shell context, such as in a Makefile recipe, rather than a proper Make context. Without more details, it's hard to offer additional guidance, beyond the observation that what you are attemping seems a bit square peg / round hole.